# How to get the data in Flux onError

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The question is not specific to database, but depicted it with the database example

- I fetch some entities from database with a reactive driver
- Convert them in Item entity using itemMapper.
- save them in database
- if error comes logs the error.

This works with below

```
 reactiveTemplate
          .query(cql, itemMapper) // This returns an item object
          .doOnNext(this::saveRecord) //this save item Object
          .doOnError(this::processErrorRecord);  // Logs the exception
```

But If I want to log which item got the error, how to access failedIte in `doOnError` method?

```
 reactiveTemplate
      .query(cql, itemMapper) // This returns an item object
      .doOnNext(this::saveRecord) //this save item Object
      .doOnError(th -> processErrorRecord(<failed Item>,th)); //how to access the item which got error
```

Comment: what is the signature of `saveRecord`? Is it reactive?

Comment: `void savItem(Item item) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to suggest something without knowing all details but here are your options. `doOnNext` is an operator typically used for "side-effect" logic such as logging, metrics, ... to execute non-reactive code. I'm not really sure why `saveRecord` is not reactive because it looks like you are using `reactiveTemplate` to query data.

In case `saveRecord` is using `reactiveTemplate` you should return `Mono<Void>` (not `void`). In this case you can apply the following

```
reactiveTemplate
        .query(cql, itemMapper) // This returns an item object
        .flatMap(record -> 
                saveRecord(record) //this save item Object
                    .doOnError(th -> {
                        log.error("error while saving record: {}", record);
                        processErrorRecord(record, th);
                    })
        );
```

Not sure what is the logic of `processErrorRecord` but in case this is reactive, use `onErrorResume` instead of `doOnError`.

In case `saveRecord` is not reactive and blocking, you need to execute it on a separate `Scheduler`. Check [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) for details

```
reactiveTemplate
        .query(cql, itemMapper) // This returns an item object
        .flatMap(record ->
                Mono.fromRunnable(() -> saveRecord(record))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())    
                    .doOnError(th -> {
                        log.error("error while saving record: {}",record)
                        processErrorRecord(record, th);
                    })
        );
```

Comment: there was an event I had to send on save success so I kept it under a method and the save record was not reactive but now I’ve moved that out of save and added it on doOnNext of saveRecord in your first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different nesting of the reactive chain.

You could attach the `doOnError()` directly to `saveRecord()`. Then, you would have the record object still in your context.

```java
reactiveTemplate
    .query(cql, itemMapper) // This returns an item object
    .doOnNext(record -> saveRecord(record) //this save item Object
                         .doOnError(th -> {
                             log.error("error while saving record: {}",record)
                             processErrorRecord(record, th);
                          })
     );
```

Comment: `saveRecord` is not reactive and you can't use `doOnError`